# Template with data binding categories as tab items with nested check boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, data-binding

I want to create a WPF-Form that has a `TabItem` inside a `TabControl` for each `Category` inside of `Checklist`.
Inside of each `TabItem` is a list of `CheckBox`es with names for each `ChecklistItem`.

This is the actual data structure:

```
public class Checklist
{
    public int ChecklistId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ChecklistItem> ChecklistItems { get; set; }
}

public class ChecklistItem
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public bool ItemChecked { get; set; }
}
```

How do I create the XAML for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `ItemContainerStyle` to set the tab header to `CategoryName` and a data template as `ContentTemplate` for the tab content. The content template uses an `ItemsControl` to display the list of `ChecklistItem` using another data template containg a `CheckBox` that binds the properties.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Checklist.Categories}">
   <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
         <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding CategoryName}"/>
      </Style>
   </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Category}">
         <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChecklistItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChecklistItem}">
                  <CheckBox Content="{Binding ItemName}" IsChecked="{Binding ItemChecked}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         </ItemsControl>
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reaction and sorry about my late response. Thats my first steps with binding in WPF and I don't really get it. Can you make an example for the code behind? Actually I got an object of type Inspection thats named "_model" and that contains all other data/classes. At the moment I get an error, that Category and ChecklistItem is not in Namespace.

Comment: Ok, got the wrong namespace. Now i fixed it, so that the DataTypes are known. But no Tabs appears. I think I made a mistake with the binding.

Comment: OK, because i bind the Checklist to the DataContext I have to change Checklist.Categories to just Categories. Now it works.